# MySql enable uppercase table names

Tags: mysql, database

I know there are a more questions aswered related to this topic but none of them helped me solve my problem. All the tables in my database are converted to lowercase but I need to import a table that has uppercase letters.

I have tried to add **lower_case_table_names=2** in **my.ini** and it didn't work out. I also tried l**ower_case_table_names=0**, that one didn't work for me as well.

**NOTES:** - Yes, I restarted MySql after making those changes).
       - I am running the Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: *I need to import a table that has uppercase letters* - why? Table and column names are normally not case-sensitive.

Comment: You don't to name tables and distinct them as upper and lower.